# Deleting repeated element if it occurs twice in the sublist of a list

Tags: python, list, recursion, iteration

if I am given a list like [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5] in Python for example and wish to delete only the first repetition for select consecutive number grouping and then break and reiterate/recurse to remove the first repetition from the second grouping etcc...How do I do it? Here's the example:

To break it down: Once the code detects the first number pair of repetitions i.e.1,1 in alist[0] and alist[1], it deletes alist[1] and prints solution by skipping the rest of the repetitions of number subgroupings. Then, it recalls itself recursively. SKIPS alist[0] and alist[1] this time as it runs through the list, and find alist[2], alist[3] has a repetition, deletes alist[3], breaks out and repeats.... eventually leading to four different outputs

```
alist = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5]
# insert code here"
>>output = 
[1,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5]
[1,1,2,2,3,3,5,5,5]
[1,1,2,2,2,3,5,5,5]
[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,5,5]
```

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please edit to give more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, groupby
>>> alist = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5]
>>> groups = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(alist)]
>>> for i, g in enumerate(groups):
        print list(chain.from_iterable(groups[:i] + [g[1:]] + groups[i+1:]))
...
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5]
```

---

Here `groups` is a list of lists containing all the groups:

```
>>> groups
[[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 5, 5]]
```

Now we can iterate over this list and slice out the first item from the current group `g` and join it with the remaining groups using slicing and `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: Thanks you! This is great!

Comment: Note that this can kill unique items in the list. But I guess that may be ok for the OP's purposes, and of course it's not a problem if the items will always have at least one repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Without using recursion recipe, you can use `itertools.groupby()` in order to group the duplicate items then consume the first item and concatenate the rest by `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`:

```
>>> def del_group(iterator):
...     for _,g in groupby(iterator):
...         next(g)
...         yield g
... 
>>> 
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(del_group(alist)))
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5]
```

But if you want all the result at each deletion you can use following function:

```
>>> def del_group(iterator):
...     groups = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(iterator)]
...     for i in range(len(groups)):
...         yield [item[1:] if ind == i else item for ind, item in enumerate(groups)]
... 
>>> list(del_group(alist))
[[[1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 5, 5]],
 [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 5, 5]],
 [[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3], [5, 5, 5]],
 [[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 5]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For each unique element in the list, remove the first instance in the list.
Use a fresh copy of the original list for each iteration.

```
import copy

alist = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5]

for item in set(alist):
    temp = copy.copy(alist)
    temp.remove(item)
    print temp
```

Comment: You may want to convert the set back to a list and sort it.

Comment: What if the list looks like `alist = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5,1,1,1]`? You should remove item using index not using value.